# Can I still use HTC Sync (OSX) software if I root my One S?

Tags: rooting, sync, htc-sync-3.0

I have run out of app space so am thinking of rooting my phone (HTC One S) to be able get rid of the many unremovable preinstalled apps that I never use.

I was wondering if the HTC Sync software on my Mac will still recognise the phone once it's rooted?

The software is a bit crap but I would like to be able to get photos off the phone via USB still.

Comment: Yes, it _should_ work. I don't have a HTC, but are you sure you actually have to use that software ? It should be possible to connect it in mtp or Mass Storage device mode, and avoid the software.

Comment: NB: Getting rid of pre-installed apps won't usually give you any *usable* space for new apps. System apps are on a completely separate partition, so you'd have to either alter your device's partition table (risky) or move other apps into the "system" app space.

Comment: @eldarerathis thanks for the info!  if I install eg cyanogen does that replace entirely the existing partitions, system apps etc?  otherwise I found some apps in Play store that can move user apps to the SD card, that would solve it for me, but not sure if they work with all phones

Comment: Custom ROMs typically don't alter your partition structure. Having said that, I do recall some situations where ROMs did things like that to try to create more usable space for apps. You may need to check the ROM developer's information (assuming they post some) for accurate details. CyanogenMod, to my knowledge, will not alter your partition table.